# How to change the color of ion-label by script?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I would like to change the color of the label {{person.name}}
by script in my .Ts file.
When I click on the button, I add the user in the array & would like to change his color to explain to the user that this one is already selected.

Here is my html code:

```
  <ion-list>
  <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let person of (personList | async)">
   
    <ion-item-options side="start">
        <ion-item-option color="danger" (click)="delete(person.id)">
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="trash-sharp"></ion-icon>
        </ion-item-option>        
    </ion-item-options>
    <ion-item class="item-content">
    <ion-label color="this.label_color[person.id]">{{person.name}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options side="end">
    <ion-item-option  (click)="add(person.id)">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="star"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item-option>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
</ion-list>
```

Here is the part of the code in the .ts file:

```
  add(user){
    const index: number = this.arr_Customers.indexOf(user);
    if (index == -1) {
      this.arr_Customers.push(user);
      this.label_color[user] = "danger";
    }          
  }
```

Thanks for reading & please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a property in your model for `person`:

**person.ts**

```
export class Person {
 name: string;
 .
 .
 selected: boolean;

 constructor() { 
 }
}
```

**CSS/SCSS**

```
.red-color {
 color: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-label [ngClass]="{'red-color': person.selected}">{{person.name}}</ion-label>
```

Now, when you add that person, just change selected to true:

```
add(user){
const index: number = this.arr_Customers.indexOf(user);
if (index == -1) {
  user.selected = true;
  this.arr_Customers.push(user);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot @manish ! You quickly & perfectly answered to my question. Have a nice day.

Comment: Sure, glad I could help.